# Laravel mysql update balance after payment

Tags: mysql, laravel

I have mysql tables:

```
Balance
id | client_id | balance
```

And

```
Payments**  
id | payment_date | amount | foreign key -> balance_id
```

What methods are used to update balance when I store payment amount?

Answer (score 0):

Inside your payments model, you can create an event handlers like so:

```
/**
 * The event map for the model.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $dispatchesEvents = [
    'created' => \App\Events\PaymentCreated::class,
];
```

Then you can create an event like so:

**PaymentCreatedEvent**

```
<?php

namespace App\Events;

use App\Models\Payments;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\Channel;
use Illuminate\Queue\SerializesModels;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\PrivateChannel;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Events\Dispatchable;
use Illuminate\Broadcasting\InteractsWithSockets;

class PaymentCreatedEvent
{
    use Dispatchable, InteractsWithSockets, SerializesModels;

    public $payments;

    /**
     * Create a new event instance.
     */
    public function __construct(Payments $payments)
    {
        $this->payments = $payments;
    }

    /**
     * Get the channels the event should broadcast on.
     *
     * @return Channel|array
     */
    public function broadcastOn()
    {
        return new PrivateChannel('channel-name');
    }
}
```

Then you can create a listener to create the balance:

**PaymentCreatedListener**

```
<?php

namespace App\Listeners;

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Mail;
use App\Events\PaymentCreatedEvent;

class PaymentCreatedListener
{
    /**
     * Create the event listener.
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
    }

    /**
     * Handle the event.
     *
     * @param PaymentCreatedEvent $event
     */
    public function handle(PaymentCreatedEvent $event)
    {
        // Insert in to the balance table here
    }
}
```

Then inside your eventserviceprovider.php add

```
/**
 * The event listener mappings for the application.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $listen = [
    'App\Events\PaymentCreatedEvent' => [
        'App\Listeners\PaymentCreatedListener',
    ],
];
```

To listen to your event. You will need to create the insert statement inside the listener... But you get the idea.

Comment: This is overkill for updating model's, simply add event listener callbacks within the model's static boot method.

Comment: Granted, but when they need to perform more actions (OP never specified if he has more use cases; like emails, slack etc) then doing it that way will be clearner

Comment: This is long term hobby project for learning purposes. In the future i may want to have mail notifications after payment. I already made upload payments from excel function. So I will try to make balance update with "events"

Answer (score 0):

In payment issues i think you must handle transaction and check that all inserts/updates run successfully.

You can one of approaches:

1.
In your payment model:

```
static function boot() {
    static::created(function($payment){
        //update balance here
    }
}
```

2.
   In your controller or other class:

```
DB::beginTransaction();

try{

    //insert payment row

    //update balance

    DB::commit();
}
catch (\Exception $e){
    DB::rollback();
}
```